# Earth doesn't have seafloor craters. Does it mean water has been on Earth since long time before in the past?

Tags: astrophysics, water, earth, comets

Is it true that Earth didn't get its water by cometes impacts as there are no subocean craters so it seems water acted as a comete bumper long before in the past?

Comment: No, generally the sea floor is fairly recent through sea floor spreading. Better perhaps on the Earth Sciences stack?

Comment: Also, much, much easier to search continents for craters than the ocean floor, though suspected sea floor impact craters have been found.

Answer (score 1):

Because the sea floor is continually being renewed through spreading and subduction, most of the sea floor is no older than something like ~250 million years. Also note that meteor impacts were much more common longer ago than that than they are today, which means that almost all of the marine impact craters have been wiped clean off the bottom long ago.